# Could not access element by ID

Tags: c#, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I am facing with problem when I tried to access Android element by ID in C#, I also tried with Appium-desktop version and seems not accessible for example:

I tried with and without package name and there is an exception every time which says could not find element. Also from Appium desktop selector.

```
AndroidElement selectPlant = driver.FindElementById("com.heidelbergcement.aom.stage.dev:id/loginForm-plantSelection")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding something.

`FindElementById` refers to the unique identifier of the element which in most cases is the RuntimeId of the UI element.

What you should use is `findElementByAccessibilityId`, which refers to AutomationId of the UI element as shown in the inspect tool.

Total credit to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/276#issuecomment-335904845).

Comment: Actually I tried with findElementByAccessibilityId and seems to work but, lets assume that we have a drop-drown menu from which can choose elements with findElementByAccessibilityId I was able to found only the first element which was chosen by default what I am trying is to get the whole list of them but apparently they are not returned.

Comment: For what I understand, you want to get the container of the dropdown menu? Has it an id? If not you should look for the parent of the element you found, and access it by XPATH.